# Change Mermaid theme in markdown

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I use mermaid for basic diagram rendering within my markdown documentation aside my code. I found [this online editor](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/) useful to edit this while having a preview. This proposes to change theme (*default* and *forest* works).

How can I set theme when I copy paste this into my markdown document ?

Answer (score 27):

It is possible to change the theme in the Markdown document with a [directive](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/directives?id=directives-1) for each figure.

Here is an example (tested with Material for Mkdocs):

````
This graph uses the forest theme:

``` mermaid
%%{init: {'theme': 'forest', "flowchart" : { "curve" : "basis" } } }%%
graph LR
A[Foo] --> B[Bar]
B --> A
```

That one uses the neutral theme:

``` mermaid
%%{init: {'theme': 'neutral' } }%%
graph LR
A[Foo] --> B[Bar]
B --> C[Baz]
```
````

The result will be:

[image: Resulting diagrams]

Comment: That's nice. Is there a way to modify it for all diagrams at once?

Comment: yes but in `mkdocs.yml`, see other posts. You may also set a jinja variable and inject it in the mermaid snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how the mkdocs parameters would look like? Sorry, I didn't find any info yet. The other posts seem to refer to older mermaid versions.

Comment: Like this: replace `- mermaid2` with `- mermaid2:\n      arguments:\n        theme: 'forest'\n        flowchart: { curve: 'basis' }` (also keep the indentation and replace each `\n` with a carriage return.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work in azure devops, which is where i am using markdown

Comment: This also work in QOwnNotes

Answer (score 25):

I was looking for the same as you, so after taking a look and digging in [Mermaid source code](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/search?q=theme&unscoped_q=theme) could find these code snippet:

```
for (const themeName of ['default', 'forest', 'dark', 'neutral']) {
  themes[themeName] = require(`./themes/${themeName}/index.scss`)
}
```

So, after testing in their editor, these themes are working fine:

- default
- forest
- dark
- neutral

You can find their themes here in case you want to build your custom themes:
https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/tree/master/src/themes

If you go to [Mermaid online editor](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/), you can change the theme to those mentioned above:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question asked still thx for the digging.

Comment: This was the answer for the question I googled "mermaid js themes" Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The theme is embedded when rendering SVG and it seems currently there is no support for custom theme setting when using markdown.

Comment: Sadly this seems to be the case, the default Theme is the ugliest of all available themes.

Comment: @phifi: See my comment under https://stackoverflow.com/a/57274389/6419007 I use the last mermaid version with Markdown and can choose the theme ('neutral' fits well with the rest of our MkDocs material doc)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, your only chance to set the theme is on initialization:

```
 mermaid.initialize({
      theme: 'forest',
      logLevel: 1,
      flowchart: { curve: 'linear' },
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what you use to produce output from your Markdown -- I use [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) with [Material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/), and added Mermaid support like explained [here](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/693#issuecomment-411885426).

After some trial-and-error configurations I found out that using Cloudflare's CDN, you can include an older version of MermaidJS with another CSS. This way, I was able to render the diagram using the neutral style:

```
markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.superfences:
      custom_fences:
        - name: mermaid
          class: mermaid
          format: !!python/name:pymdownx.superfences.fence_div_format

extra_css:
  - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/7.0.9/mermaid.neutral.css
extra_javascript:
  - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/7.0.9/mermaid.min.js
```

Comment: I ended up downloading the last version (https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.4.3/dist/mermaid.min.js), looked for `theme:"default"`, replaced it with `theme:"forest"` and saved the js locally, e.g. to `js/mermaid.min.js`. It worked fine and I can use the last version.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the [stylesheet](https://mermaidjs.github.io/#/sequenceDiagram?id=styling) detailed in the documentation, modify it and add `!important` after every CSS property you change, it will take precedence over the inline styles Mermaid copies into the SVG. Far from ideal, but neither is the copying of styles Mermaid does, so this is a "fighting fire with fire" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your tool chain or targeted output format is.

That being said, you can use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) with [mermaid-filter](https://github.com/raghur/mermaid-filter) to export a Markdown file containing a Mermaid chart to a couple of formats.

Plus, with mermaid-filter you can select the theme using the fenced code block's key-value attributes options

E.g. let /tmp/example.md contain the following

````
```{.mermaid theme=forest}
graph TD
A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
B --> C{Let me think}
C -->|One| D[Laptop]
C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
```
````

then

```
pandoc --filter mermaid-filter --from markdown --to html /tmp/example.md > /tmp/example.html
```

will produce the an HTML page /tmp/example.html that looks as follows

[image: example mermaid chart]