# Mermaid - Custom CSS & Scripts in Markdown

Tags: css, github, markdown, mermaid

`tl;dr` For a Markdown page on Github, how can I specify a styling sheet and source script for a mermaid diagram?

I'm looking through [mermaid's Flowchart documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart) and foud a lot of cool features like being able to specify a `callback`. However, I'm struggling to figure out how one would go about doing this in Markdown.

I've figured out how to change the theme from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535327/change-mermaid-theme-in-markdown), and am using inline `classDef` for styling as explained in [the docs](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=styling-and-classes), but still not sure how I'd go about using a custom styling sheet and defining a callback that's not just a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Mermaid's syntax allows you to use [inline directives](https://mermaid.js.org/config/directives.html#declaring-directives) in the Mermaid content, that directs how it should render.  You can pass it the same parameters you would pass in `init()`, such as this example for [sequence diagrams](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html#possible-configuration-parameters).

I did a quick test with the following, and it seems to work:

````
I am in a Markdown file and I want to show you a diagram:

```mermaid
%%{
  init: {
    "sequence": {
      "actorFontFamily": "monospace",
      "actorFontWeight": "bold",
      "messageFontFamily": "monospace",
      "messageFontWeight": "bold",
      "noteFontWeight": "bolder"
    }
  }
}%%

sequenceDiagram
  autonumber
  participant Browser
  participant AppServer

  rect rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.05)
    note over Browser, AppServer: (Phase 1) Authentication Check

    Browser ->> AppServer: GET /admin { Cookie:  }
    Browser ->> Browser: useSession
  end
end
```
````

Changing things like font sizes does not always result in an apparent change (I suppose the SVG must be scaled to the available size in your browser), but you can try changing the "theme" to verify the directive is being processed.

Comment: Nice proof of concept, but is it possible to put the styling (theme) in a separate file, to be referenced by multiple md files?

Comment: @OlaEldøy I don't know of a way off the top of my head, but I can see where it would be useful to separate the styling from the content (it's what I usually do for front-end code).  I did later experiment with using `classDef` (which appears to take plain CSS) in a flowchart.  If you can find a way to get external styles visible in the scope of the markdown document, maybe then you could refer to them in a mermaid diagram?

Answer (score -1):

You probably cannot.

[GitHub strips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956450/354577) most [styling out of its README files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28201503/354577). I would be very surprised if there were a special case permitting custom styling of Mermaid diagrams.